# can you place markers on an axis or define constraints on the size of a mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm a novice to blender and 3d modelling software in general. I'm making a game involving custom character parts and I have constraints needed on the length along the x axis. For example the width of a torso part so shoulders and arms can fit properly. I'm wondering if you are able to define constraints within blender on the mesh or place some kind of markers on a axis

Comment: you can use a background image with the body sketch to work on it easily , and there's no constraints for mesh